# Will ajax work in dot.net framework 2.0?

Tags: asp.net

I have vs2005.Now I installed 2008 also in my machine(both are there).Previouly when I was opening my vs 2005 solution file,there was no ajax control. Now it shows me ajax control in it.(but solution file show vs2005).Will it cause any error in future?

Comment: "does not showing me ajax control" means? do you added any ajax control in your vs2005 project?

Comment: @mahesh, I understood that as "the ajax controls aren't in the toolbox."

Comment: I think it will be more appropriate to ask questions when you do have a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont. However, you need to convert your poject to 2008.

`UpdatePanel` and the other *ajax extensions* controls have been release on 2008 in .net framework 3.*. You can not add an `UpdatePanel` control to a project that is built on previous frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.I tried to add update panel control in vs 2005 solution file.It says that it is not known element.I got the answer of question.If it shows the control in toolbox(may be because of installation of 2008),but it is not working.

Comment: Have you tried to convert your project to 2008 and work on vs 2008 ?? `UpdatePanel` and the other _ajax extensions_ controls have been release on 2008 in .net framework 3.*. You can not add an `UpdatePanel` control to a project that is built on previous frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  ASP.NET AJAX was released with .NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 (which is why 2005 doesn't have the controls in the toolbox).

Comment: i think ajax 1.0 can be used with .net 2.0